# Problems with JSON

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I'm trying to Order in ascending order the requirements that are not between 25,000 and 30,000. The requirements are information of an array which is inside of a document and the condition is that they can't be in that determined range. I'm trying to do it properly but i can't find any information about this.

Document structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec73abebd7e4d618a05734e"),
    "code" : "A47",
    "title" : "Software engineer",
    "description" : "Analyze, design, create, test computer and software systems.",
    "city" : "Madrid",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-22T02:36:46.271Z"),
    "salary" : 30000.0,
    "active" : true,
    "requirements" : [ 
        "python", 
        "java", 
        "html5", 
        "C++", 
        "C#"
    ],
    "info_company" : {
        "cif" : "A00000000",
        "name" : "FUTURE S.A",
        "location" : "Madrid",
        "web" : "www.future.es",
        "about" : "We are a leading company in new technologies."
    },
    "pyme" : true
}
```

```
db.offers.update( 

{ $ne : [ salary: {

            $gte : 25000,
            $lte : 35000 ]
 } },
    {
   $push : {
          requirements:  { 
              $each : [] ,
              $sort : 1 
                           }    
           }
    }
        , 
     { 
       multi : true 
     } )
```

Comment: What is the document structure? Is it really spelled "requeriments" in the documents? What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong spelled. I just edited the question